# What access rights do I need to create a subscription to a devops workitem on behalf of a user?

Tags: azure-devops, devops, power-automate

TL;DR What access rights do I need to have to be able to use the notification API to create a subscription on behalf of a user?

---

I'm trying to subscribe a user to a new DevOps work item I'm creating in a PowerAutomate flow. But, when the flow tries to do that, I get an unauthorized response.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/notification/subscriptions/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#definitions

[Example of step in PowerAutomate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcNok.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.